# Using jQuery, how do I select dynamic related data keys on an element and output them into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, given this HTML:

```
<div class="playlist"
     data-name1="Some Name 1"
     data-value1="123"
     data-name2="Some Name 2"
     data-value2="456"
     data-name3="Some Name 3"
     data-value3="789"
></div>
```

I want to return an array of key/value pairs like so (using jQuery):

```
[{
    "name": "Some Name 1",
    "value": "123"
}, {
    "name": "Some Name 2",
    "value": "456"
}, {
    "name": "Some Name 3",
    "value": "789"
}]
```

Here is some pseudo code that I thought about but obviously doesn't work:

```
array = []
$(".playlist").attr("data-name-*, data-value-*").each(function(name, value){
   array.push({"name": name, "value": value});
  }
})
return array;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var length_data = Object.keys($(".playlist").data()).length/2;

var data = []
for (i = 1; i <= length_data; i++) {
    data.push({"name" : $(".playlist").attr('data-name'+i), "value" : $(".playlist").attr('data-value'+i)} )
}
```

[DEMO here](https://jsfiddle.net/wvhe31j9/)

**Update**
For prevent when u had more data :

```
var length_data = Object.keys($(".playlist").data()).length/2;

var data = []
for (i = 1; i <= length_data; i++) {
    if (typeof $(".playlist").attr('data-name'+i) == "undefined" || typeof $(".playlist").attr('data-value'+i) == "undefined" ) continue;
        data.push({"name" : $(".playlist").attr('data-name'+i), "value" : $(".playlist").attr('data-value'+i)} )

}
```

[Demo update](https://jsfiddle.net/bdz38oqs/2/)

Comment: Sorry about my previous confused comment :) Your solution looks great. What I did notice though is that it's adding one extra object that's undefined:

[{
    "name": "Some Name 1",
    "value": "123"
}, {
    "name": "Some Name 2",
    "value": "456"
}, {
    "name": "Some Name 3",
    "value": "789"
}, {
    "name": undefined,
    "value": undefined
}]

Do you know what's causing that issue?

Comment: Yeah, because i calculated length with number of attribute, if u have more attribute then needed, it will loop for "data-name4" and this is undefined. What you can do for prevent this is to add : `if (typeof $(".playlist").attr('data-name'+i) == "undefined" || typeof $(".playlist").attr('data-value'+i) == "undefined" ) continue;` Before pushing, check update jsfiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/bdz38oqs/2/

Comment: I'm sure there is far better solution, but i thinks it works.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the updated solution. That works great for me. Thank you so much Rossi :)

Answer (score 1):

```
array = []
  $.each($('.playlist')[0].attributes, function(i, attrib){
    array.push({name : attrib.name, value : attrib.value});

  });
  console.log(array);
```

Comment: You need to create demo if you want to get upvote or mark.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution Khaled. I did notice that it's adding unneeded objects. Can we remove those too? I tried it for example using this HTML element, https://jsfiddle.net/m45264jp/ and saw unneeded objects were added

Answer (score 1):

This can give you something to work with. It works.

```
var attributes = $('.playlist')[0].attributes;
var total_attr = attributes.length - 1;

var test = [];
for (var i = 1; i < attributes.length; i += 2) {
    var attr = attributes[i];
    var value = attributes[i+1];
    var temp = {};

    temp['name' + i] = attr.nodeValue;
    temp['value' + i] = value.nodeValue;
    test.push(temp)
}
console.log(test)
```

Comment: Thanks e4en. I did get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error. I changed the attributes to $('.playlist')[0].attributes, but still got a "Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined" error. I appreciate your help though. I got the solution above from A. Rossi, but thanks so much for trying to help me

Comment: Yes, that works great now :) Thank you e4en. I accepted A. Rossi's solution above and I wish I could accept yours too. Your solution works great too. Thank you so much e4en